# How to implement the first interaction model in Google Analytics for funnel reporting?

Tags: google-analytics, tracking, reporting

We use standard and custom reporting in Google Analytics. But for our reports we need to change the attribution model. In https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1665189 we have found that  Analytics uses Last Non-Direct Click model by default when attributing conversion value in non-Multi-Channel Funnels reports.

How would we switch to another default model? Multi-Channel Funnels and Model Comparison Tool are not suitable. We need custom report with First Interaction model.

Answer (score 1):

To view data on various attribution models in GA:

Conversions > Attribution > Model Comparison

Comment: Thanks. We know about this report. But we can't edit metrics in it and can't  add required dimensions. We need change attribution model in other standard and custom reports.

Comment: My apologies, I don't think it's possible to change the default attribution model in Analytics.